# How do I insert the combined elements of two separate lists with the same index to another list?

Tags: python, list

I am creating a scheduling algorithm using python. And it seems I am having a problem with lists.

Here is the problem:

I have 2 lists: A_list and S_follow.

```
A_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
S_follow = [[2,3],4,[5,6],8,7,9,8,10,10,11,0]
```

Now, I have created another list which is called `Prece_list`

What must happen is that,

`Prece_list` elements should have

```
 Prece_list = 

 [
     [1,[2,3]],
     [2,4],
     [3,[5,6]],
     [4,8],
     [5,7],
     [6,9],
     [7,8],
     [8,10],
     [9,10],
     [10,11],
     [11,0]

]
```

The following data inserted in the list.

How do I make that happen? How do I create that list without manually inserting those data?

So far, I have been using for loops but I can’t seem to solve my problem, still.

This is what I have coded so far:

```
# Add Precedence Constraint
Larger_S = []
Prece_list = []

for j in range(0, len(A_list)):
  for s in range(2, max_row+1):
    # convert to activity number
    A_list[s] = S_follow
    Prece_list.append(A_list[s])
    print(Prece_list)
    Larger_S.append(Prece_list)
    print(Larger_S)
```

Comment: Why do you want that specific data structure? It seems inconsistent. i.e. it would make more sense to keep the second element to alway be a list even if it has one element so `[[1, [2, 3]], [2, [4]], ...]`. It would also be more natural to make this a list of tuples rather than a list of lists since you know each item always has two element and the positions are meaningful. It also means the solution is as simple as `Prece_list = list(zip(A_,list, S_follow))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [map](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map) builtin to achieve that:

```
map (lambda a,b: [a or 0, b or 0], A_list, S_follow)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
A_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
S_follow = [[2,3],4,[5,6],8,7,9,8,10,10,11]

Prece_list = []

for i in range(0, len(A_list)):
    temp_list = []
    temp_list.append(A_list[i])


    try:
        temp_list.append(S_follow[i])
    except IndexError as e:
        temp_list.append(0)
    Prece_list.append(temp_list)
print(Prece_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `zip` built-in function:

```
Prece_list = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(A_list, S_follow)]
```

Similarly:

```
Prece_list = list(map(list, zip(A_list, S_follow)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way:

```
A_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
S_follow = [[2,3],4,[5,6],8,7,9,8,10,10,11,0]

A_list = [[n,S_follow[n-1]] for n in A_list]
print(A_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, [2, 3]], [2, 4], [3, [5, 6]], [4, 8], [5, 7], [6, 9], [7, 8], [8, 10], [9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for enumerate and list comprehension like:

```
Prece_list = [[v, S_follow[i]] for i, v in enumerate(A_list)]
```

Or

```
Prece_list = [[A_list[i], v] for i, v in enumerate(S_follow)]
```